# How to restore existing Site Collection Content DB to a SharePoint Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, backup, content-database, restore

I have a Site Collection Content DB back up. I want to create/ restore to existing site collection. Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: Do u want overwrite the existing site collection?

Comment: Yes @WaqasSarwarMVP

Comment: Lukas already respond it, if that does not meet your requirement then could you please add more detail in your question, where is the database, how much sites in the db, do you have test farm? what version of sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only Attach an existing content database to a web application, while cannot attach an existing content database to a site collection.

To attach an existing content database to a web application:

1.Restore a backup copy of the database in SQL.

2.Use the following PowerShell to attach an existing content database to a web application:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName
```

Refer to the article about Attach or detach content databases in SharePoint 2013:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify which version of SharePoint you have. But if it is at least 2010, unattached content database can be used.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/hh269601(v=office.14).aspx

1. Restore the database to SQL server
2. Use PowerShell or UI to restore the site collection you need

Comment: Mount-SPContentDatabase command to mount DB with Web app. But can be used to restore the site collection as well.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to restore site collection that already exist in the farm (e.g. you want fo back in time) you won’t be able to mount the database.